# SQL trigger for auto-generation of strings

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `T_USER` that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE T_USER (
  ID_USER             NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  LASTNAME            VARCHAR2(75 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME           VARCHAR2(75 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  LOGIN               VARCHAR2(75 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  PASSWD              VARCHAR2(168 BYTE) NOT NULL,
  ACTIVE              NUMBER(1) /* IF USER IS ACTIVE OR NOT */
);
```

> **ID_USER** is the primary key, **LOGIN** is unique

---

I would like to auto-generate user's login when a USER with `ACTIVE = 0` is inserted.

The login is the **first letter of the firstname**, **5 first letters of lastname** and a **random number** in [1-50]. If the new user does not have a firstname, it is a company, so we just take the 6 first letters from its name (+ random number).

---

Some examples:

- `FIRSTNAME: Bruce, LASTNAME: Wayne` should generate `LOGIN: bwayne13`
- `FIRSTNAME: Peter, LASTNAME: Parker` should generate `LOGIN: pparke45`
- `FIRSTNAME: NULL, LASTNAME: Google Inc`should generate `LOGIN: google6`

---

I'm pretty new to SQL triggers, there is what I've done so far:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GENERATE_LOGIN
BEFORE INSERT ON T_USER
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (ACTIVE = 0)
DECLARE
    LOG T_USER.LOGIN%TYPE;
BEGIN
IF(:NEW.LOGIN IS NULL) THEN
    IF(:NEW.FIRSTNAME IS NULL) THEN /* It's a company */
        SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.LASTNAME,'[^A-Z0-9]')),'ç','c') /* I remove non alphanumeric characters */
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;

    ELSE /* It is a real person */
        SELECT SUBSTR(:NEW.FIRSTNAME, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(:NEW.LASTNAME, 1, 5) 
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END IF;

:NEW.LOGIN := LOG;

END;
/
```

As you guess, my trigger does not work (I have [ORA-04076 error](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ORA-04076&safe=active&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=oWxaV87DFsOsaZeVrKgP)). By the way, I also do not check if the generated login is unique...

May you help me? :)

Comment: for the ora error, replace when(active=0) by when (new.active=0) in your third line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a proposal with unicity check.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GENERATE_LOGIN
BEFORE INSERT ON T_USER
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.ACTIVE = 0)
DECLARE
    LOG T_USER.LOGIN%TYPE;
    nlogin number(10); -- counter for the unicity
BEGIN
IF(:NEW.LOGIN IS NULL) THEN
   loop
    IF(:NEW.FIRSTNAME IS NULL) THEN /* It's a company */
    SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.LASTNAME,'[^A-Z0-9]')),'ç','c')     /* I remove non alphanumeric characters */
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;

    ELSE /* It is a real person */
        SELECT SUBSTR(:NEW.FIRSTNAME, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(:NEW.LASTNAME, 1, 5) 
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;
    END IF;


select count(login) into nlogin from t_user where login=log; -- checking
exit when nlogin=0; -- exiting the loop if none else have that login


end loop;
:NEW.LOGIN := LOG;  -- moved this here, as it doesn't make sense after the end if, log has not been defined in that case
END IF;




END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks, it solves my problem! I just had my filter of alphanumericals to the `ELSE` case, and use `TRUNC(DMBS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50))`, because it generated random values with 38 digit precision.

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this syntax before where `FOR EACH ROW WHEN (ACTIVE = 0)` is part of the trigger header. Apparently it is where the error is coming from. When you remove it, the trigger compiles successfully. To me, it does not make sense, because the compiler does not know whether `ACTIVE` you are referring to here is the old or the new value. Maybe someone else can clarify this part further.

Anyway, I could replace it with a traditional IF statement, and the trigger compiles successfully:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GENERATE_LOGIN
BEFORE INSERT ON T_USER
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    LOG T_USER.LOGIN%TYPE;
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.ACTIVE = 0) THEN  --replace WHEN (ACTIVE = 0)
IF(:NEW.LOGIN IS NULL) THEN
    IF(:NEW.FIRSTNAME IS NULL) THEN /* It's a company */
        SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.LASTNAME,'[^A-Z0-9]')),'ç','c') /* I remove non alphanumeric characters */
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;

    ELSE /* It is a real person */
        SELECT SUBSTR(:NEW.FIRSTNAME, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(:NEW.LASTNAME, 1, 5) 
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END IF;

:NEW.LOGIN := LOG;

END IF;
END;
/
```

**Update**

Upon checking, you can use this syntax, with `NEW` keyword (without colon). So the same trigger can be rewritten like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GENERATE_LOGIN
BEFORE INSERT ON T_USER
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.ACTIVE = 0) THEN
DECLARE
    LOG T_USER.LOGIN%TYPE;
BEGIN
IF(:NEW.LOGIN IS NULL) THEN
    IF(:NEW.FIRSTNAME IS NULL) THEN /* It's a company */
        SELECT REPLACE(LOWER(REGEXP_REPLACE(:NEW.LASTNAME,'[^A-Z0-9]')),'ç','c') /* I remove non alphanumeric characters */
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;

    ELSE /* It is a real person */
        SELECT SUBSTR(:NEW.FIRSTNAME, 1, 1) || SUBSTR(:NEW.LASTNAME, 1, 5) 
        || DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50) /* Concat random in [1-50] */
        INTO LOG FROM DUAL;
    END IF;
END IF;

:NEW.LOGIN := LOG;

END;
/
```

Read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg13trg.htm)

Comment: `FOR EACH ROW WHEN (ACTIVE = 0)` works well for me, maybe we don't have the same version... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Mistalis Are you sure `FOR EACH ROW WHEN (ACTIVE = 0)` without `NEW` worked for you? Your comment on Gar's answer says otherwise!